# Proper use of get_range to make a chart

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using the following code to attempt to make a charge and it is throwing a com exception.  I am attempting to make a chart.  Is there something obvious my code is doing wrong?  The error is thrown on the get_range line.

```
      static void makechart(int counter, int startcount, Worksheet sourcesheet)
    {
        Range chartrange;
        string rangestr = "G" + startcount.ToString() + ":G" + counter.ToString() + ",I" + startcount.ToString() + ":I" + counter.ToString();
        ChartObjects xlcharts =     (ChartObjects)sourcesheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlcharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
        chartrange = objsheet.get_Range(rangestr,Type.Missing);
        //chartrange = sourcesheet.get_Range("G1", "B" + counter + 1);

        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartrange, Type.Missing);
        chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlBarClustered;


    }
```

Comment: objsheet?? where is that defined? Do you mean sourcesheet?

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Replace:

```
string rangestr = "G" + startcount.ToString() + ":G" + counter.ToString() + ",I" + startcount.ToString() + ":I" + counter.ToString();
```

with:

```
string range1 = "G" + startcount.ToString() + ":G" + counter.ToString();
string range2 = "I" + startcount.ToString() + ":I" + counter.ToString();
```

and

```
chartrange = objsheet.get_Range(rangestr,Type.Missing);
```

with:

```
chartrange = objsheet.get_Range(range1,range2);
```

Comment: The error is still there, I am wondering if I am missing something?